# Blender render transparency in 3d view. Normals/faces shading issues

Tags: materials, 3d-view

what is causing that shading effect ? I need the bottle to be a little transparent and some faces  inside are not recieving any transparency. The effect dissappears when I set alpha to less than 0.3

I have tried recalculating and fliping normals, also checked the box  for double sided in ''type of data to display and edit'' shelf. I am out of ideas.

[image]

It looks like the effect is happening where the mesh has edges. Also mesh is subd'ed.

Comment: Not sure which effect you're trying to get, but try changing transparency method to Z-Transparency. This will create not masking but alpha transparency.

Comment: i basicaly need a transparent material to display in  the 3d view

Comment: backface culling helped a little bit but not entirely.